# Slidingdrawer in a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, slidingdrawer

Has anyone successfully put a slidingdrawer in a fragment?

I get unspecified dimension exceptions unless I specify the width and height of the drawer in dip (which isn't ideal for supporting large/small screen devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the idea of a SlidingDrawer is that it sticks to the edge of your screen. since you can choose to place fragments anywhere you can in an activity's layout, it's probably not the best idea to use it inside a fragment's layout.

although you can set the limit to where your sliding drawer slides before it's considered `isOpen()` using basic layout heirarchy tricks.

will have to confirm this once i set up eclipse on this machine

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I was about to try it but didnt know if it was possible either